# Viewing score in different activities

Tags: android

I am trying to view high score in 3 different activities. I am using sharedpreference.
1. The game itself, together with the current score.
2. shareIntent - for social media
3. High score List.

I am having a problem on viewing the topscore on the 3rd one. I wanted it this way: If the user clicks on a certain category, the highest score for that category must be displayed n a textview. I put the codes for this at the onFinish on my countdown. I only wanted to show the shareIntent after the timer finished. But as you can see the Highscore activity also pops out. I wanted to start the intent for viewing the highscore on the list WHEN the user goes to the activity itself and ONLY when the user clicks the category. Is it possible that way? Please bear with my codes. TIA :)

P.S. First app, first try, total newbie :)

**onFinish**

```js
@Override
  public void onFinish() {
   timer.setText("Time's Up!");

            
                topScore.setText(score.getText());
                run();

                Intent i = new Intent(TimeAttack.this,ta_TopScore.class);
                i.putExtra("ta_score", topScore.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);

                Intent ab = new Intent(TimeAttack.this,Highscore.class);
                ab.putExtra("ta_score", topScore.getText().toString());
                startActivity(ab);
```

**HighScore List**

```js
ta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    ta_ts = getIntent().getStringExtra("ta_score");
                    score.setText(ta_ts);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    score.setText("FAILED HAHAHA");
                }
}
        });
```

Comment: It´s not clear enough, but if I am understand Your problem the wright way, just delete the second Intent ab = new Intent(TimeAttack.this,Highscore.class);....and the two lines below.´You are starting two activities at the same time..

Comment: yes I am starting 2 activities, because the Highscore class should also get the score in that activity so I come up that way.

Sir/mam (prosper, I think?) i'm sorry. okay so my problem is that I want to get the score via intent. This score must be viewed in another activity called Highscore. This activity shows lists of highscore of different categories. How can I do that? Accessing and starting an an intent and via button from a different activity?

Comment: @LabLey: Code is implemented in right way let me know what problem getting using current code?

Comment: no problem with the codes. But i wanted the Intent ab to only get started when the user clicks on the button (which is located in a different activity) for the score to view on that activity, not on the game's activity.

Comment: @LabLey: But you are showing data in textview on `ta` Button click

Comment: yes. But the problem is that whenever the tmer goes of (see onFinish method) 2 activities starts. I want the Intent ab to start only when ta is clicked.

Comment: in which activity you have `ta` button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72023/discussion-between--k-and-lab-ley).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it.

You need to store score in local variable and use it later to start Highscore activity.

```
private String mTopScore;

public void onFinish() {
        timer.setText("Time's Up!");
        mTopScore = score.getText().toString();

        topScore.setText(mTopScore);
        run();

        Intent i = new Intent(TimeAttack.this, ta_TopScore.class);
        i.putExtra("ta_score", mTopScore);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

And then from whatever place user need to tap to open Highscore activity you pass it with intent:

```
 goToHighScoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(mTopScore != null){
            Intent ab = new Intent(TimeAttack.this,Highscore.class);
            ab.putExtra("ta_score", mTopScore);
            startActivity(ab);
        }else{
            //do something boring
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: haha okay I laughed so hard at the last point :D I'm so sorry Im confused too haha XD So I wanted to do it like this:         From the game itself: after the countdowntimer ends, the shareIntent will appear. Purpose: for the user to share its score. ---------------- If I am a new user/player, lets say that I wanted to view the high scores for every categories. So i wil go to highscore screen/activity. Upon pressing a button (equiv. to one categ) i should see the highest score for this category. (Thats why I made 2 intents in nFinish method so that it could get the score)

Comment: Where are you going to Highscore activity from? User need to press something to go there? Looks like you are forcing user to go there now. It automatically opens after timer ends.

Comment: yes. and tats my problem. So the user's path upon viewing the highscore list must be like splashscreen > menu > Highscore. I don't want the user to  go there after the time finishes off. I only wanted the shareIntent there (intent i) and if the user goes back to menu, and chooses to go to the Highscore, then that should be the time the Intent ab is activated.

Comment: I've tried the codes above >.< but it won't show anything X3

Comment: the gotoHighScoreActivity button is outside the TimeAttack activity. It is like other game which provides a list of highscores. If a player wanted to view the highscore BEFORE playing the game then the path be like: Splash screen > menu > highscore > The List (hereis the button gotoHighscoreActivity is located. :)

While if the player wanted to play the game:
Splash screen > menu > Time Attack > The game

Comment: @LabLey Then save your high score in sharedpreference and just get it in Highscore activity.